# Stats has output in se mode, but is always empty in fs mode

Tags: gem5

This is my command line：

> build/ALPHA/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --ruby --l1i_size=2kB --l1d_size=1kB --l1i_assoc=2 --l1d_assoc=2 --l2_assoc=4 --l2_size=8kB --num-l2caches=16 -n 16 --num-dirs=16 --topology=Mesh_XY --mesh-rows=4 --cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU

I'm sorry because I'm a beginner and I'm not sure if I have the right layout

This is my system.pc.com_1.device:

```
Linux version 2.6.22.9 (blackga@nacho) (gcc version 4.1.2 (Gentoo 4.1.2)) #2 Mon Oct 8 13:13:00 PDT 2007

Command line: earlyprintk=ttyS0 console=ttyS0 lpj=7999923 root=/dev/hda1

BIOS-provided physical RAM map:

 BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 (usable)

 BIOS-e820: 000000000009fc00 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)

 BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 0000000020000000 (usable)

 BIOS-e820: 0000000020000000 - 00000000c0000000 (reserved)

 BIOS-e820: 00000000ffff0000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)

end_pfn_map = 1048576

kernel direct mapping tables up to 100000000 @ 8000-d000

DMI 2.5 present.

Zone PFN ranges:

  DMA             0 ->     4096

  DMA32        4096 ->  1048576

  Normal    1048576 ->  1048576

early_node_map[2] active PFN ranges

    0:        0 ->      159

    0:      256 ->   131072

Intel MultiProcessor Specification v1.4

MPTABLE: OEM ID:  MPTABLE: Product ID:  MPTABLE: APIC at: 0xFEE00000

Processor #0 (Bootup-CPU)

Processor #1

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #2

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #3

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #4

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #5

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #6

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #7

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #8

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #9

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #10

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #11

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #12

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #13

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #14

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

Processor #15

WARNING: NR_CPUS limit of 1 reached. Processor ignored.

I/O APIC #16 at 0xFEC00000.

Setting APIC routing to flat

Processors: 1

swsusp: Registered nosave memory region: 000000000009f000 - 00000000000a0000

swsusp: Registered nosave memory region: 00000000000a0000 - 0000000000100000

Allocating PCI resources starting at c4000000 (gap: c0000000:3fff0000)

Built 1 zonelists.  Total pages: 127570

Kernel command line: earlyprintk=ttyS0 console=ttyS0 lpj=7999923 root=/dev/hda1

Initializing CPU#0

PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 11, 16384 bytes)

time.c: Detected 1999.972 MHz processor.

Console: colour dummy device 80x25

console handover: boot [earlyser0] -> real [ttyS0]

Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)

Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)

Checking aperture...

Memory: 509248k/524288k available (3742k kernel code, 14444k reserved, 1874k data, 232k init)

Calibrating delay loop (skipped)... 3999.96 BogoMIPS preset

Mount-cache hash table entries: 256

CPU: L1 I Cache: 64K (64 bytes/line), D cache 64K (64 bytes/line)

CPU: L2 Cache: 1024K (64 bytes/line)

using mwait in idle threads.

CPU: Fake M5 x86_64 CPU stepping 01

ACPI: Core revision 20070126

ACPI Exception (tbxface-0618): AE_NO_ACPI_TABLES, While loading namespace from ACPI tables [20070126]

ACPI: Unable to load the System Description Tables

Using local APIC timer interrupts.

result 7812392

Detected 7.812 MHz APIC timer.

NET: Registered protocol family 16

PCI: Using configuration type 1

ACPI: Interpreter disabled.

Linux Plug and Play Support v0.97 (c) Adam Belay

pnp: PnP ACPI: disabled

SCSI subsystem initialized

usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs

usbcore: registered new interface driver hub

usbcore: registered new device driver usb

PCI: Probing PCI hardware

PCI->APIC IRQ transform: 0000:00:04.0[A] -> IRQ 16

PCI-GART: No AMD northbridge found.

Time: tsc clocksource has been installed.

NET: Registered protocol family 2

IP route cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)

TCP established hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)

TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)

TCP: Hash tables configured (established 65536 bind 65536)

TCP reno registered

Total HugeTLB memory allocated, 0

Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).

io scheduler noop registered

io scheduler deadline registered

io scheduler cfq registered (default)

Real Time Clock Driver v1.12ac

Linux agpgart interface v0.102 (c) Dave Jones

Serial: 8250/16550 driver $Revision: 1.90 $ 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled

serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 8250

floppy0: no floppy controllers found

RAMDISK driver initialized: 16 RAM disks of 4096K size 1024 blocksize

loop: module loaded

Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.20-k2

Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation.

e100: Intel(R) PRO/100 Network Driver, 3.5.17-k4-NAPI

e100: Copyright(c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation

forcedeth.c: Reverse Engineered nForce ethernet driver. Version 0.60.

tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6

tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>

netconsole: not configured, aborting

Uniform Multi-Platform E-IDE driver Revision: 7.00alpha2

ide: Assuming 33MHz system bus speed for PIO modes; override with idebus=xx

PIIX4: IDE controller at PCI slot 0000:00:04.0

PCI: Enabling device 0000:00:04.0 (0000 -> 0001)

PIIX4: chipset revision 0

PIIX4: not 100% native mode: will probe irqs later

    ide0: BM-DMA at 0x1000-0x1007, BIOS settings: hda:DMA, hdb:DMA

    ide1: BM-DMA at 0x1008-0x100f, BIOS settings: hdc:DMA, hdd:DMA

hda: M5 IDE Disk, ATA DISK drive

hdb: M5 IDE Disk, ATA DISK drive

ide0 at 0x1f0-0x1f7,0x3f6 on irq 14

hda: max request size: 128KiB

hda: 1048320 sectors (536 MB), CHS=1040/16/63, UDMA(33)

 hda: hda1

hdb: max request size: 128KiB

hdb: 4177920 sectors (2139 MB), CHS=4144/16/63, UDMA(33)

 hdb: unknown partition table

megaraid cmm: 2.20.2.7 (Release Date: Sun Jul 16 00:01:03 EST 2006)

megaraid: 2.20.5.1 (Release Date: Thu Nov 16 15:32:35 EST 2006)

megasas: 00.00.03.10-rc5 Thu May 17 10:09:32 PDT 2007

Fusion MPT base driver 3.04.04

Copyright (c) 1999-2007 LSI Logic Corporation

Fusion MPT SPI Host driver 3.04.04

Fusion MPT SAS Host driver 3.04.04

ieee1394: raw1394: /dev/raw1394 device initialized

USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver v3.0

usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp

drivers/usb/class/usblp.c: v0.13: USB Printer Device Class driver

Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...

usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage

USB Mass Storage support registered.

PNP: No PS/2 controller found. Probing ports directly.

serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1

serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12

mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice

input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /class/input/input0

device-mapper: ioctl: 4.11.0-ioctl (2006-10-12) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com

input: PS/2 Generic Mouse as /class/input/input1

usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid

drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-core.c: v2.6:USB HID core driver

oprofile: using timer interrupt.

TCP cubic registered

NET: Registered protocol family 1

NET: Registered protocol family 10

IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver

NET: Registered protocol family 17

EXT2-fs warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended

VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem).

Freeing unused kernel memory: 232k freed


INIT: version 2.86 booting


mounting filesystems...

loading script...

Script from M5 readfile is empty, starting bash shell...

[01;31m(none)[01;34m / #[00m ls

[00m[01;34mbin[00m   [01;34mdev[00m  [01;32mhello[00m  [01;36mlib[00m    [01;34mlib64[00m       [01;34mmnt[00m  [01;34mproc[00m  [01;34msbin[00m  [30;42mtmp[00m  [01;34mvar[00m

[01;34mboot[00m  [01;34metc[00m  [01;34mhome[00m   [01;34mlib32[00m  [01;34mlost+found[00m  [01;34mopt[00m  [01;34mroot[00m  [01;34msys[00m   [01;34musr[00m

[m[01;31m(none)[01;34m / #[00m ./hello

Hello world!

[01;31m(none)[01;34m / #[00m
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you exit the simulation correctly with an [`m5 exit` call](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/0f8131833e49df9b585111de44d68ab200b51595#m5-exit), or a the corresponding [m5op exit instruction](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/0f8131833e49df9b585111de44d68ab200b51595/packages/kernel_modules/user/m5ops.h#L15)?

gem5 dumps stats by default when exiting correctly due to this line: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/7a6183aa6162419912daa5647d13f030ab0904e2/src/python/m5/simulate.py#L165 Why: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-dev@gem5.org/msg27603.html

Alternatively, you can also use an `m5 dumpstats` call or the corresponding m5op to explicitly dump the stats: this is the most common use case (together with `m5 resetstats`), as it gives you greater control over what stats are being dumped.